# React multiple filter functionality on an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I am working on this React JS assignment in which I am fetching data and displaying it on my screen.  Here's my code:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState();
  const [filteredJobs, setFilteredJobs] = useState();

  const jobData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(" http://localhost:3031/jobs");
    const json = await data.json();
    setJobs(json);
    setFilteredJobs(json);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    jobData();
  }, []);

  const cityFilter = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === "All") {
      setFilteredJobs(jobs);
    } else {
      const newJobs = jobs.filter((val) => val.location === e.target.value);
      setFilteredJobs(newJobs);
    }
  };

  const expFilter = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === "All") {
      setFilteredJobs(jobs);
    } else {
      const newJobs = jobs.filter((val) => val.yoe === e.target.value);
      setFilteredJobs(newJobs);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div>
        <select name="select city"  onChange={cityFilter}>
          <option value="All"> All</option>
          <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
          <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
          <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
          <option value="New Delhi">New Delhi</option>
          <option value="Gurugram">Gurugram</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select name="select experience" onChange={expFilter}>
          <option value="All">All</option>
          <option value="Internship">Internship</option>
          <option value="Fresher">Fresher</option>
          <option value="Early Professional">Early Professional</option>
          <option value="Professional">Professional</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          padding: "8px",
          gap: "4px",
          justifyContent: "center",
          marginTop: "8px",
        }}
      >
        {filteredJobs?.map(({ id, title, img, location, role, yoe }) => {
          return (
            <JobCard
              key={id}
              id={id}
              title={title}
              
              location={location}
              role={role}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Currently I am stuck on applying multiple filters at the same time e.g, say a particular city is selected from filter option, a filtered city list is shown but when I go on to select another filter it filters from all my fetched API rather than selecting from city filtered data. I was trying to solve this issue by using useeffect but I am getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should give a default value to your state variables, so `const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);`

Second, you do not have to keep data that can be derived from the state, as a state variable. So you do not really need the `filteredJobs` variable to come from `useState`.

Third, you should name each `select` with the actual property in the jobs you want them to apply to.

```html
<select name="location">
  <option value="All"> All</option>
  <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Then, i would use state for the actual filters and group them in a single variable.

```js
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
```

and to update them using a single handler

```js
const updateFilter = useCallback((e) => {
  setFilters((currentFilters) => ({
    ...currentFilters,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  }));
}, []);
```

and

```html
<select name="location" onChange={updateFilter}>
```

Finally the `filteredJobs` can be filled from applying the `filter` on the `jobs` like this

```js
const activeFilters = Object
  .keys(filters)
  .filter(key => filters[key] !== 'All');

const filteredJobs = jobs.filter((job) => {
  return activeFilters
    .every(key => job[key] === filters[key]);
})
```

Small demo at: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/amazing-frog-fmmps3

Comment: Thank you very much, can you suggest some docs/videos to learn about useCallback hooks.

Comment: @HarshdeepSingh the official docs do a pretty good job. https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback Also i had forgotten to add the empty dependency list.

Answer (score 0):

Since `jobs` does not change during the component's operation, we use `useRef` for it.

Multiple filtering can be implemented using the `filters` state.

```js
const Home = () => {
  const jobs = useRef([]);
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    byCity: undefined,
    byExp: undefined
  }); 

  const jobData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(" http://localhost:3031/jobs");
    const json = await data.json();
    jobs.current = json;
    setFilters({...filters}); // for update component
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    jobData();
  }, []);

  const addCityFilter = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === "All") {
      setFilters((prev) => ({ ...prev, byCity: undefined}))
    } else {
      const byCity = (arr) => arr.filter((item) => item.location === e.target.value)
      setFilters((prev) => ({...prev, byCity}))
    }
  };

  const addExpFilter = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === "All") {
      setFilters((prev) => ({...prev, byExp: undefined}))
    } else {
      const byExp = (arr) => arr.filter((item) => item.yoe === e.target.value)
      setFilters((prev) => ({...prev, byExp}))
    }
  };

  let filtered = jobs.current
  for (const filter of filters) {
    filtered = filter?.(filtered) || filtered
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div>
        <select name="select city"  onChange={addCityFilter}>
          <option value="All"> All</option>
          <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
          <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
          <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
          <option value="New Delhi">New Delhi</option>
          <option value="Gurugram">Gurugram</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select name="select experience" onChange={addExpFilter}>
          <option value="All">All</option>
          <option value="Internship">Internship</option>
          <option value="Fresher">Fresher</option>
          <option value="Early Professional">Early Professional</option>
          <option value="Professional">Professional</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          padding: "8px",
          gap: "4px",
          justifyContent: "center",
          marginTop: "8px",
        }}
      >
        {filtered.map(({ id, title, img, location, role, yoe }) => {
          return (
            <JobCard
              key={id}
              id={id}
              title={title}
              
              location={location}
              role={role}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```